# What is the difference between these two examples?

Tags: python-2.7, static-methods

I am going through this Python Tutorial -

[Static Method, Class Method](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods)

```
class Pizza(object):
    @staticmethod
    def mix_ingredients(x, y):
        return x + y

    def cook(self):
        return self.mix_ingredients(self.cheese, self.vegetables)

>>> Pizza().cook is Pizza().cook
False
>>> Pizza().mix_ingredients is Pizza.mix_ingredients
True
>>> Pizza().mix_ingredients is Pizza().mix_ingredients
True
```

I don't quite understand the result of --->  Pizza().cook is Pizza().cook - > Why are they different?

And Pizza().mix_ingredients is Pizza.mix_ingredients -> What is the difference between having the bracket and no bracket?

Finally, for static method, why is the final result True?

Many thanks!

Comment: There are more details than you can dream of here: http://blindvic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/explaining-bound-and-unbound-methods-in.html BTW WHy do you want the static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to think about this is to see the `cook` method as being one per `Pizza`, whereas all `Pizza`s share the *same* `@staticmethod` `mix_ingrecdients`.

So `Pizza()` gives you a new pizza, thus `Pizza().cook` is the cook method of a specific pizza (indicated by `self`) so,

```
Pizza().cook is Pizza().cook
```

will therefore be `False`.

This partially answers the next part of your question.
Pizza is the type and Pizza() is an instance of the type. When you refer tho the static method this gives the same function:

```
>>> Pizza().mix_ingredients
<function mix_ingredients at 0x7f62a5eae668>
>>> Pizza.mix_ingredients
<function mix_ingredients at 0x7f62a5eae668>
```

If you try this for the instance method, you will get "bound" and "unbound" functions.